# How do you set the default Backend Layout in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I am using the method of defining Backend Layouts in a TSconfig file in a site package extension.

```
mod {
  web_layout {
    BackendLayouts {
      # pagets__onecolumn 
        onecolumn {
          title = One column
            config {
              backend_layout {
                colCount = 1
                rowCount = 1
                rows {
                  1 {
                    columns {
```

...
   etc

I would now like to define one of my own BE-Layouts as default.

I found a method of excluding BE-Layouts (such as "none") in the select list in page properties:

```
TCEFORM.pages.backend_layout_next_level.removeItems= -1
TCEFORM.pages.backend_layout.removeItems= -1
```

But what I really want is for TYPO3 to automatically assign my default BE-Layout to new pages (and not use the TYPO3 default).

---

Using TYPO3 8 (latest version)

Comment: In most cases it wont be needed but also not even desired. If you have the field just empty TYPO3 will `slide` up till the right Layout is found and display that. If all pages get a value you've to change each single page if a BE-layout is changed for a whole branch. Assume you want to add or remove a sidebar for a branch.

Comment: That makes sense. So you mean it will use the BE-Layout that is set in the next page in the rootline by default? I will try this.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant ;-)

Comment: ok, I just tested this: Created a  page and explicitly set a BE layout, then created a child page and did not set any BE Layout. The child page however, uses the default TYPO3 BE layout (as I can see because normal, right,left and border is displayed).

Comment: You've two fields, one for the BE-layout of the current page and one for the next level. If you've never set that a default BE-layout shall be used the layout of a page in the hierarchy up is searched for an entry in next level layout and that will be used.
Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Got it! Now it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, welcome  ;-)

Comment: @David: make your comments into an answer, so dale can accept it. others might find the solution easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the TYPO3 page records there are two fields for backend layouts on the current page and backend layouts on subpages. The latter is assigned automatically to each of the pages in the tree below the page where you set it.

So you should just assign your default layout as backend layout on subpages within the root page and it will become the default for any page, that hasn't got a layout set itself.

You can override that by selecting another layout on a subpage, that will override the default setting for that particular part of the tree.

Comment: Of course you're right that you can solve it via the two fields, but assuming you want to explicitly set a default value, the following TsConfig should work, but unfortunately it doesn't (maybe a bug): TCAdefaults.pages.backend_layout = pagets__onecolumn

Comment: I just wrote an issue report: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89685